# C# function that takes pointer to function as an in parameter without declaring any specific delegate types?

Tags: c#, delegates

I want to implement a method that will find stuff in my custom class. It should work like generic collections work - i pass a pointer to a function, and the method will iterate through all it has to look in, apply this function, and if it returns true return the found item.

I'd like to pass function pointer as a parameter, but i dont want to declare delegate types.

I know i can do something like:

```
delegate bool Foo(MyClass)
MyClass MyMethod(Foo x)
{...}
```

And i know i can do something like this:

```
MyClass MyMethod(Func<MyClass,bool> x)
```

But can i do it without declaring a delegate type and without using built in stuff like Func<> which has limits on how many parameters i can have (in case of Func, one...)

Comment: Well, maybe you can have function with an object array?

Comment: In .NET 3.5, `Func` can have more than one parameter. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.90).aspx  see: http://i.imgur.com/yQIaf.png

Comment: Thanks. Still, is there a way to declare the type of delegate inside the method declaration, or do i HAVE to use Func<>?

Comment: You can do it with a *string* by using Reflection.  But that's going to be slow, crash prone and hard to read.  Problems that a delegate doesn't have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use *delegate* if you want, although it's a bit old school :)

```
public void TestInvokeDelegate()
{
    InvokeDelegate( new TestDelegate(ShowMessage), "hello" );
}

public void InvokeDelegate(TestDelegate del, string message)
{
    del(message);
}

public delegate void TestDelegate(string message);

public void ShowMessage(string message)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(message);
}
```

Comment: I want to have public void InvokeDelegate(TestDelegate del, string message)
 without the need to declare TestDelegate - i want to state "function InvokeDelegate takes a function pointer which takes string and returns void" - can i do it?

Comment: No you can't do it, you're thinking of C++.  What's the problem with Func<> or Action<>?

Comment: There is none, i just asked if i can do it or not :)

Answer (score 0):

You can allways pass in a [Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y22acf51.aspx) and call [DynamicInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.dynamicinvoke.aspx) on it:

```
MyClass MyMethod(Delegate x) {
    // ...
    x.DynamicInvoke(....);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: In other words Delegate represents a generic method, which i can pass any paramters to and expect any value in the end? Its like "object" of functions?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to implement the [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). In this case visiting methods usually have only one parameter - the instance to visit. Having additional arguments passed around conceals the use of the pattern and makes it harder to reason about. [This article](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternVisitor.aspx) shows you one way to implement it in C#.

The key is to create a visitor class that will encapsulate all the parameters that affect the visiting process. This way you don't need to pass anythnig other than an object in question in the visiting method - everything else lives in instance fields.

However, if you really want to pass some additional parameters in the method and don't know what type they can have, there are ways to do that. More or less standard approach in .NET world is to use a delegate without return value and with single parameter of type `object`, the example would be [ParameterizedThreadStart delegate](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternVisitor.aspx):

```
public delegate void ParameterizedThreadStart(
    Object obj
)
```

This way you get to pass only one parameter in the delegate, but it could be anything - an instance of a class, an array or null, if you end up not needing additional arguments after all. The downside of this approach is that it requires type casting which can lead to runtime errors.

Comment: @Istrebitel: well, the thing you are describing in the first paragraph is *exactly* what the Visitor pattern is invented for, so you should probably look into it

Comment: No, actually, i just need a search function for my custom TreeView that searches around the tags of the treenodes. So i want to pass a function pointer to it, and it will apply this function to each treenode until True is encountered. The parameter for the method is TreeNode that is checked. Now, i just wanted to know if i can do this without declaring a delegate type